# How to access the name of first class after instantiating multiple classes nestedly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some classes with its own functions in python. In the function of first class I create an object of second class and inside of a function in second class, I create an object of third class and in a function of the third class, I need to know what is the name of first class. I wrote an example to show the problem in the following:

```
class first:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def func1(self):
    class2 = second()
    class2.func2()

class second:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def func2(self):
    class3 = third()
    class3.func3()

class third:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def func3(self):
    print(" what is the name of first class?" )
```

Is there any way to print "first" as the output?

Comment: This doesn't really make a lot of sense. If `func3` needs information, then *the caller should pass that information explicitly as an argument*. So in `second.func2` you should do something like `class3.func3("first")`

Comment: btw, using the variable name `class3` for an object *that isn't a class* is kind of confusing

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a reference to the first class instance down the chain of method calls, so that it is available to the third class when it needs it.

Here’s an example:

```
class first:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func1(self):
        class2 = second()
        class2.func2(self) # pass a reference to the first class instance

class second:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func2(self, class1):
        class3 = third()
        class3.func3(class1) # pass the reference to the first class instance

class third:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func3(self, class1):
        print(class1.__class__.__name__) # print the name of the first class

class1 = first()
class1.func1() # prints "first"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
import inspect

class third:

 def init(self):
  pass

def func3(self):

 current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
 caller_frame = 
 inspect.getouterframes(current_frame, 2)
class1_name = caller_frame[1] 
[0].f_locals["self"].class.name
print(f"The name of the first class is{class1_name}")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please keep in mind that SO is English only (I've translated the first sentence). And please format your code appropriately. In its current form it doesn't run.